# Removing duplicate entries from a comma separated string column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have multiple columns in which I merged all the values from previous columns containing strings and separated them with a comma. The only issue is that by doing so it apparently "kept" any duplicate values even though I removed the duplicates based on the column that the merge was done so for the value "5" on column Col_A the corresponding value on Col_B is James,Maria,Harrison.

Unfortunately the output looks something like: James,Maria,James,Harrison,Maria,Marina,Harrison which is what I've been trying to get rid of with various methods such as apply and split.

Here is my latest attempt:

```
Import pandas as pd
Import numpy as np

df1['Col_B'] = ','.join(set(df1['Col_B'].split(',')))
df1

Original output:

  Index         Col_A                              Col_B
     0            5               Maria,Harrison,James,Harrison,Maria,Maria
     1            2               Maria,Jimmy,Emma,Jim,Jim,Maria,Jimmy,Jimmy
     2            46                                 ...
     3            184                                ...
     4            31                                 ...
     5            81                                 ...

Desired output:

  Index         Col_A        Col_B
     0            5    Maria,Harrison,James
     1            2    Maria,Jimmy,Emma,Jim
     2            46           ...
     3            184          ...
     4            31           ...
     5            81           ...
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated it. Looked for some time online but wasn't able to locate a solution for this exact application.

Comment: first you could create normal function for single string - and later you could use `.apply()` to run it for all rows in column.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of ways to do this,

if the original order is of no consequence then

```
df['Col_B'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x : ','.join(set(x)))
```

or

```
df['Col_B'].str.split(',').apply(pd.unique)

0     [Maria, Harrison, James]
1    [Maria, Jimmy, Emma, Jim]
2                        [...]
3                        [...]
4                        [...]
5                        [...]
```

Comment: The only issue is that now the error "'float' object is not iterable" comes which could be because the string contains both numbers and letters so it's slightly different from the one that I have put up. But nonetheless the format of the variable is object which in my mind should "solve" that error. Or I am thinking wrong?

Comment: @Alexchristof20 you have `NaN` values which are float types.  `df['Col_B'].fillna('').str.split(',').apply(pd.unique)` or just drop the na values

Comment: By using your latest recommendation the result was the same as previously, as if nothing happened. But by using your .fillna rec with the first of the two options: 'df['Col_B'].str.split(',').apply(lambda x : ','.join(set(x)))' it worked perfectly and thank you for that! One final question, what you think would be the most efficient way with huge datasets to check what substrings are in common from Col_A & Col_B and store them into a 3rd column, otherwise 'NA'?

Comment: @Alexchristof20 open a new question and do a good [mcve] you'll get a good answer :)